# FIO reports slower sequential read than the advertised NVMe SSD read bandwidth

Tags: io, ssd, nvme, fio

## TLDL

For the very simple sequential read, FIO reports is much slower than the NVMe SSD sequentail read capability.

---

## Main Text

Hello everyone,

I have been facing an issue while trying to achieve the maximum read bandwidth reported by the vendor for my Samsung 980 Pro 1T NVMe SSD. According to the Samsung product description, the SSD is capable of reaching read bandwidths of around 7 GB/s. However, despite my efforts, I have been unable to achieve this maximum read bandwidth.

Current Setup:

- SSD: Samsung 980 Pro 1T NVMe SSD
- Connection: PCIe 4.0 port
- Operating System: Linux Ubuntu

Current FIO Script and Results:
To test the read performance of the SSD, I have been using the FIO benchmarking tool with the following script:

```bash
$ sudo fio --loops=5 --size=1024m --filename=/dev/nvme0n2 --stonewall --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --zero_buffers=1 --name=Seqread --bs=1024m --iodepth=1 --numjobs=1 --rw=read
```

Here are the results obtained from running the FIO script:

```
Seqread: (g=0): rw=read, bs=(R) 1024MiB-1024MiB, (W) 1024MiB-1024MiB, (T) 1024MiB-1024MiB, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=1
fio-3.28
Starting 1 process
Jobs: 1 (f=1)
Seqread: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=1504682: Mon Oct 16 09:28:48 2023
  read: IOPS=3, BW=3368MiB/s (3532MB/s)(5120MiB/1520msec)
    slat (msec): min=151, max=314, avg=184.19, stdev=72.71
    clat (msec): min=2, max=149, avg=119.59, stdev=65.39
     lat (msec): min=300, max=316, avg=303.77, stdev= 7.33
    clat percentiles (msec):
     |  1.00th=[    3],  5.00th=[    3], 10.00th=[    3], 20.00th=[    3],
     | 30.00th=[  148], 40.00th=[  148], 50.00th=[  148], 60.00th=[  148],
     | 70.00th=[  150], 80.00th=[  150], 90.00th=[  150], 95.00th=[  150],
     | 99.00th=[  150], 99.50th=[  150], 99.90th=[  150], 99.95th=[  150],
     | 99.99th=[  150]
   bw (  MiB/s): min= 2048, max= 4096, per=81.07%, avg=2730.67, stdev=1182.41, samples=3
   iops        : min=    2, max=    4, avg= 2.67, stdev= 1.15, samples=3
  lat (msec)   : 4=20.00%, 250=80.00%
  cpu          : usr=0.00%, sys=31.47%, ctx=405, majf=0, minf=262156
  IO depths    : 1=100.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=5,0,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=1

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=3368MiB/s (3532MB/s), 3368MiB/s-3368MiB/s (3532MB/s-3532MB/s), io=5120MiB (5369MB), run=1520-1520msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  nvme0n2: ios=9391/0, merge=0/0, ticks=757218/0, in_queue=757218, util=93.39%
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on **how to optimize my FIO script to achieve the expected read bandwidth of around 7 GB/s**. If there are any improvements or modifications that can be made to the script, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Please feel free to provide any additional information or insights that may be relevant to the issue at hand.

---

Note:

It should be PCIe4.0*4:

```
$ lspci -vv -s 5e:00.0
5e:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 39
    NUMA node: 0
    IOMMU group: 84
    Region 0: Memory at c5e00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme

$ cat /sys/class/pci_bus/0000\:5e/device/0000\:5e\:00.0/max_link_width 
4
$ cat /sys/class/pci_bus/0000\:5e/device/0000\:5e\:00.0/max_link_speed 
16.0 GT/s PCIe
```

Comment: looks like Gen 3 speed - how is the NVMe connected to your system? onboard m.2? Which motherboard? PCIe adapter? Which one?

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX. I have updated to ensure a PCIe4.0*4 connection. I found some post that the FIO also reached ~3.0G/s as my case: https://www.phoronix.com/review/samsung-980-pro/2 . So I also don't understand why can't this blog have 7G/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consider increasing the test size or simply removing the limit. Using `--size=1024m` means you're targeting a specific range of NAND flash, which can limit the bandwidth.
2. Opt for a time-based option and a smaller block size. By specifying `--bs=1024m` and the same size, you're essentially completing each loop with a single I/O from `fio` (though it will be divided into many smaller I/Os at the block layer), leading to potentially biased results.
3. Increase the I/O depth. It's unlikely that any SSD's spec numbers are based on a single job and depth of 1.

Consider trying the following command:

```shell
sudo fio --time_based --runtime=300 --filename=/dev/nvme0n2 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --bs=1024k --iodepth=128 --numjobs=1 --rw=read --name=read --group_reporting
```